# Camera Error when after accessing video capture again, MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE

Tags: android, video, camera, video-recording

I am experimenting on video recording on my project and I am accessing it using this. Also my test device is Nexus 5 version 4.4 KitKat.

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
```

So, it directs me to the video intent. Then when i press back button to return the app to its main view, and launch the video recording again, I get "Camera Error: Can't connect to the camera".

I have to open built-in camera app on the device and close it so that I can open it on my project.

Note :
My main view is a customized view for my image capture that has a preview, from there I have a button that executes the code above for the video capture. So, what is happening is somewhat like this (in sequence) :

> 1. at MainView press button for video intent
> 2. (when video finish/cancel)
> 3. goes back to MainView
> 4. (press button for video intent again)
> 5. "Camera Error: Can't connect to the camera".

Here are the codes to initialize my Camera.

This is on my main view :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCameraLoader.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mCameraLoader.onPause();
}
```

These are functions that are in the CameraLoader class:

```
public void onResume() {
    setUpCamera(mCurrentCameraId);
}

private Camera getCameraInstance(final int id) {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = mCameraHelper.openCamera(id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ASDA", "" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return c;
}

private void setUpCamera(final int id) {
    mCameraInstance = getCameraInstance(id);
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCameraInstance.getParameters();
    if (parameters.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(
            Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
    }

    
    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    for (int i = previewSizes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((previewSizes.get(i).height == DEF_HEIGHT)
                && (previewSizes.get(i).width == DEF_WIDTH)) {
            mCameraSize = previewSizes.get(i);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mCameraSize.width, mCameraSize.height);
            Log.e("preview_sizeness", "index: " + i + "    width: " + previewSizes.get(i).width
                    + "    height: " + previewSizes.get(i).height);
            break;
        }
    }
    mCameraInstance.setParameters(parameters);

    int orientation = mCameraHelper.getCameraDisplayOrientation(this.activity,
            mCurrentCameraId);
    CameraHelper.CameraInfo2 cameraInfo = new CameraHelper.CameraInfo2();
    mCameraHelper.getCameraInfo(mCurrentCameraId, cameraInfo);
    boolean flipHorizontal = cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
    mGPUImage.setUpCamera(mCameraInstance, orientation, flipHorizontal, false);
    Camera.Parameters paramss = this.mCameraInstance.getParameters();

    paramss.setRotation(90);

    this.mCameraInstance.setParameters(paramss);
}

public void onPause() {
    releaseCamera();
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    mCameraInstance.setPreviewCallback(null);
    mCameraInstance.release();
    mCameraInstance = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out. What was actually happening was that the camera, somehow, never finds a chance to close itself properly because of how fast the activities process. So, by the time video intent was closing, it immediately sets up Camera, thus, setting up the Camera while it was already had been set up. Also, since Camera was not properly handled, going back to the video intent results in Camera Error.

To fix this, I just have to delay the processes to give the Camera time to close itself. My app does not crash anymore.

Cheers!